# Display items from Splist in Textboxes only takes one Item not two

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

[image]

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://wingtip:49074"))
            {
                LabelShowTitle.Text = string.Empty;
                LabelShowContents.Text = string.Empty;
                LabelShowDatum.Text = string.Empty;
                LabelAuthor.Text = string.Empty;
                LabelLink.Text = string.Empty;

                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(DropDownListSelectCategory.SelectedItem.Value);

                DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

                SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems();

                {
                    foreach (SPListItem news in items)
                    {
                        TextBoxContents2.Text = news["Contents"].ToString();
                        LabelShowTitle2.Text = news["Title"].ToString();
                        //LabelShowContents.Text = news["Contents"].ToString();
                        LabelShowDatum2.Text = news["Date"].ToString();
                        LabelAuthor2.Text = news["Authors"].ToString();
                        LabelLink2.Text = new SPFieldUrlValue(news["Links"].ToString()).Url;

                        TextBoxContents.Text = news["Contents"].ToString();
                        LabelShowTitle.Text = news["Title"].ToString();
                        //LabelShowContents.Text = news["Contents"].ToString();
                        LabelShowDatum.Text = news["Date"].ToString();
                        LabelAuthor.Text = news["Authors"].ToString();
                        LabelLink.Text = new SPFieldUrlValue(news["Links"].ToString()).Url;
                    }
                    site.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

My Problem is that i want it to display in the first news on news that i have created in my list as u see and in the other one display the other news "My other News"

Answer (score 0):

With your code it will only take values from single list item. You can use following code to achieve what you want:

```
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems();
                    TextBoxContents2.Text = items[0]["Contents"].ToString();
                    LabelShowTitle2.Text = items[0]["Title"].ToString();
                    LabelShowDatum2.Text = items[0]["Date"].ToString();
                    LabelAuthor2.Text = items[0]["Authors"].ToString();
                    LabelLink2.Text = new SPFieldUrlValue(items[0]["Links"].ToString()).Url;

                    TextBoxContents.Text = items[1]["Contents"].ToString();
                    LabelShowTitle.Text = items[1]["Title"].ToString();
                    //LabelShowContents.Text = news["Contents"].ToString();
                    LabelShowDatum.Text = items[1]["Date"].ToString();
                    LabelAuthor.Text = items[1]["Authors"].ToString();
                    LabelLink.Text = new SPFieldUrlValue(items[1]["Links"].ToString()).Url;
```

However, I would advise that you do a proper error handling.

Comment: Hi! I works find but when i create new news its puts the latest news that i have created in the buttom

Comment: You need to actually define your requirements properly. This code will show only two news items. You can have several items in the list. What is your logic of getting the list items? Do you need the latest/oldest two news items.

Comment: Hi! I need the latest news items. I think maybe i can have an SPquery to solve it but i dont now how to write the query or what do u think?